# Recursive directory search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

So I have a function here that *should* take the path to an archive.zip as an argument, and recursively dive in to every sub directory until it finds a file with the extension .html

```
def path_to_project
    "#{recursive_find(File.dirname(self.folder.path))}"
end
```

path_to_project is used to apply this recursive_find process on the fly as a string, since it's used repeatedly in the process as a whole.

```
def recursive_find(proj_path)
    Dir.glob("#{proj_path}/*") do |object_path|
        if object_path.split(".").last == "html"
            @found_it = File.dirname(object_path)
        else
            recursive_find(object_path)
        end
    end
    @found_it
end
```

Anyways, I have two questions for the smart folks of stackoverflow-

1- Is my use of the @found_it instance variable correct? , perhaps I should use attr_accessor :found_it instead?  Obviously named something else that isn't stupid.. maybe :html_file.

Perhaps -

```
    unless @found_it
    # do the whole recursive thing
    end
    return @found_it 
    # I don't actually have to return the variable right?
```

2 - Could my recursive method be better? I realize this is pretty open ended so by all means, flame away you angry dwellers. I gladly accept your harsh criticisms and whole heartedly appreciate your good advices :)

Comment: you could go into an infinite loop as your recursive call does not have a base case, what if there is no file matching "html"

Comment: Do you need to use recursion? Can't you do something like `Dir["#{proj_path}/**/*.html"]` that will give you all the files that have html extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use recursion you could just do

`Dir["#{proj_path}"/**/*.html"]` That should give you a list of all the files that have `html` extension.

As far as your questions: Your use of `@found_it` depends on the bigger scope of things. Where is this function defined a class or a module? The name of the variable itself could more meaningful like `@html_file` or maybe what the context of the file is like `@result_page`.

Comment: Once again the answer is much simpler than I thought it was. -- For part 2 this instance variable is defined in a class

Comment: An accessor for the instance variable would be good depending on how you perceive your method. If its a Query type method I'd expect it to return the results, if its a Command type method I'd expect it to change the state of the class but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class is a very easy to use, and scalable solution. It descends into a directory hierarchy, returning each element as it is encountered. You can tell it to recurse into particular directories, to ignore files and directories based on attributes, and it is very fast.

This is the example from the documentation:

```
require 'find'

total_size = 0

Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
      Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    total_size += FileTest.size(path)
  end
end
```

I use this to do several scans of directories containing thousands of files. It's easily as fast as using a glob.